# Application Customizers no longer working on dev sites

Tags: spfx, spfx-extensions

My Application Customizers have stopped working on "Development" site templates on my developer tenancy. I get the following warning in the browser developer tools.

Invalid location: Extension.ApplicationCustomizer

However, on modern team sites and communication sites, it does work, but placeholders are Top and Bottom rather than PageHeader and PageFooter.
Any ideas what is happening here? I've tried updating the generators and building projects again but same issue....

Thanks,
Tony